# Fragment that covers bottom navigation and loads smoothly

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

My app uses a Bottom Navigation, which is tied to a NavController. I want to load a fragment that creates a new item in my app, so I want the fragment to take up the part of the screen used by the bottom navigation.  I am trying to make my app consistent with Google's, so I am using a fast entry animation from the bottom.

However, by default, the NavController loads in the NavHostFragment which is above the BottomNavigationView, so the Bottom Navigation is shown with any fragment.  I tried using the Google's suggested method to [Listen for navigation events](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#listen_for_navigation_events).  However this sets the BottomNavigationView to gine before the fragment navigation takes places, shifting the current fragment downward, giving a stutter effect on navigation.

What makes things worse is that it seems with just about any complexity of the target fragment, it takes a moment to inflate the layout of the new fragment, so the BottomNavigationView disappears, the app pauses for a moment while inflating, and then it is too late for the animation and the fragment stutters into existence.

What is the right approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the exit transition of the every those `Fragments` from which another `fragment`(which creates new item) is loaded like this:
`setExitTransition(new Hold());`
Basically, this holds the current fragment until next one is loaded.
Note: If you do not find `Hold` class in your current implementation, you might need to use the alpha version of `MaterialComponents`.
`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha01'`